# Скрипт розыгрыша призов

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте, появилась идея создать сервис на подобие сервиса snooit. Долгие поиски скрипта данной системы или же примера не увенчались успехом. Есть ли где нибудь во всемирной паутине пример данной системы ?

Comment: Это чего, тупо бабки капают с рекламы и на процент покупаются подарки и "благородно раздаются"? [bux.to](http://bux.to) 2.0 ?)

Comment: Нет. Мне нужно так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопочку рандомному пользователю доставался предмет введенный мной. Но сначала те кто хотят участвовать должны скинуться на лотерею этого приза. Как наберется нужное количество человек произойдет розыгрыш.<br><br>

и еще<br>
"появилась идея создать сервис на подобие сервиса snooit."
<br><br>
Тем более в snoit нет рекламы. Ни разу там ее не видел.

Comment: пиши с нуля сам.

Comment: Уже думал об этом... но это слишком много мороки. Мне нужен скрипт как у snooit. Рандомная раздача при нажатии на кнопку.

Comment: Мне нужены скрипты всего сервиса Google, вместе с серверами. Не завалялось случайно у кого?)

Comment: Печально, что тут сказать...

Comment: Я и не прошу заходить в snooit. Много разнообразных описаний существует.

Comment: @Palmervan я бы тоже не отказался от серваков гугла

Comment: вам на фриланс ;)

Comment: кому?) тому кто хочет серверы гугла?))

Comment: че за гон ребята?

Answer (score 2):

> Уже думал об этом... но это слишком
> много мороки. Мне нужен скрипт как у
> snooit. Рандомная раздача при нажатии
> на кнопку.

А как ты хотел? Чтобы кто-то бесплатно тебе дал движок от системы которая приносит прибыли? 
С таким же успехом можно и в банк придти взять у них на условии и без расписки бабла.

Нет, тут самому писать. Просто так деньги в нете не капают, их "заслужить" нужно.

Других вариантов нет. Хочешь зарабатывать - работай!

> Здравствуйте, появилась идея создать
> сервис на подобие сервиса snooit.
> Долгие поиски скрипта данной системы
> или же примера не увенчались успехом.
> Есть ли где нибудь во всемирной
> паутине пример данной системы ?

А тут тебе поможет моск + написание ТЗ к проекту. разработка структуры БД и прочего, что пригодиться в проекте. просто так ничего не найдёшь.

про вопрос

> Здравствуйте, появилась идея создать
> сервис на подобие сервиса snooit.
> Долгие поиски скрипта данной системы
> или же примера не увенчались успехом.
> Есть ли где нибудь во всемирной
> паутине пример данной системы?

И вот последнее предложение это вопрос, а первое это ответ, если уж на то пошло.

Comment: Вопрос был. Ответа не было. Перечитай мой вопрос. =)